# jQuery regex validation: unsigned integer or float (max 2 decimal), only dot, not comma

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm in trouble: i need a regex that match this

VALID:

```
3
44
55.5
66.66
777
```

NOT VALID:

```
3,3
.4
.55
-7
```

The regex must validate only unsigned integer or float, only dot (not comma), max 2 decimal.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the below,

```
^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

`^` Asserts that we are at the start. `$` asserts that we are at the end. Basically anchors are used to do an exact string match. `\d{1,2}` matches one or two digits.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jL4eP9/4)

Comment: try `[0-9]` instead of `\d`